# How can I remove extra space corner of the CardView?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am developing cv Android app used CardView but there is empty space corner of CardView.

below screenshot of the app
[current ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx75B.jpg)

below XML where I have implemented CardView.I think it is because of background color what is your suggestions

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorBlust"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="30dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/about"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/about_me"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/introduction"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:gravity="start" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove the radius from cradview in your layout file

Answer (score 0):

remove the corner radius of your cardview 
card_view:cardCornerRadius="18dp"

Comment: maybe you can help with this post as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116155/textview-autosizetexttype-not-working-as-expected