# TextView autoSizeTextType not working as expected

Tags: android, textview

I am developing cv and don't know how can I add free space inside a TextView after each word after 'About Me'.
I have followed this [link](https://medium.com/over-engineering/making-the-most-of-textview-auto-sizing-on-android-a39f71b6f3af).
Below is some XML where I have implemented AutoResizing, where I am not able to achieve what I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:ignore="NamespaceTypo">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorBlust"
            card_view:cardElevation="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
                    android:id="@+id/circularImageView"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:civ_border_color="#374255"
                    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
                    app:civ_shadow="false"
                    app:civ_shadow_color="#374255" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/about"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/about_me"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/introduction"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
                    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="16sp"
                    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```